# Bring ScrollView to front

Tags: xcode, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I have a View, inside this view I have on the right side some buttons and a ScrollView.

When you press one of the buttons, the scrollview comes up and more buttons are shown.
Now when you press one of the buttons of the scrollview in the main view is placed a image and the scrollview animated thru the right side.

When I push the next button, the scrollview is under the image and not over the image :(

I'ved tried to place some code at the scrollview to bring it in front

```
[waende bringSubviewToFront:waende];
```

or

```
[waende bringSubviewToFront:button];
```

but still doesn't work 
In the IB the ScrollView is in Foreground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution code is:

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:waende];
```